# mysql row turning into attributes

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I need help with an `<input>`. Some times when I call for the var to be inserted into the `value=""` part of the `<input>` it makes every word into an attribute.
For example my tag will look like this `<input type="hidden" name="article" this="" is="" the="" article="" text="" />`

and the call to the `<input>` is this 
`echo '<input type="hidden" name="article" value="'.$row['article'].'" />';`

below is the actual code

CODE:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="date_added" value="'.$row['date_added'].'" />';  
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'" />'; 
echo '<input type="hidden" name="article" value="'.$row['article'].'" />'; 
echo '<input type="hidden" name="pub_date" value="'.$row['pub_date'].'" />';
```

OUTPUT:

```
<input type="hidden" "="" added.="" snow,"="" shoveling="" those="" times,="" four="" years="" two="" real="" worn="" only="" "i've="" balance."="" i'm="" feels,="" actual="" where="" point="" gotten="" i've="" shoes.="" thing,"="" different="" whole="" ground,="" can="" "when="" world."="" senses="" off="" closing="" disconnected.="" time.="" all="" gloves="" wearing="" likens="" feeling."="" addicting="" an="" almost="" it's="" you,="" around="" world="" feeling="" used="" "you="" them,"="" comfortable="" you're="" wear="" choosing="" more="" "it's="" feet.="" your="" feel="" lifestyle"="" "barefoot="" calls="" being="" enjoys="" things="" explained="" experience."="" textures="" many="" "there's="" greatest,"="" "chautauqua="" chautauqua,="" trailhead="" favorite="" group's="" boulder="" aurora="" members="" year-round="" hikes="" day?"="" my="" rest="" what="" well,="" at,="" look="" have="" you="" that,="" explore="" start="" "but="" society,"="" prolific="" because="" thing,="" now="" attention="" people's="" grabbing="" what's="" members,="" 100="" surpassed="" recently="" grown="" has="" their="" it?="" why="" thought,="" hiking,="" enjoyed="" since="" home,="" clients="" works="" she's="" day="" spending="" already="" brushaber="" group.="" join="" first="" who="" practitioner="" movement="" brushaber,="" kriste="" organizing="" partner="" hartman's="" hiking.="" eventually,="" walking="" kept="" marathon,="" run="" change.="" change."="" would="" pain.="" back="" time,="" at="" marathon="" training="" problems.="" other="" few="" splints="" shin="" hartman="" ago,"="" while="" running.="" trying="" after="" started="" group="" meetup="" range="" front="" hartman,="" mary="" thing."="" natural,="" this="" into="" getting="" are="" "people="" he="" (shoes),"="" our="" trail="" appalachian="" guys="" "we="" sashen="" somewhere,"="" some="" top="" them="" me="" showing="" people="" from="" pictures="" testimonials="" get="" walking.="" nearly-barefoot="" for="" footwear="" sandals="" vibram-soled="" light="" makes="" which="" shoes,="" invisible="" founder="" sashen,="" steven="" says="" deal,="" big="" becoming="" minimalist="" boom.="" running="" heels="" on="" popularity="" in="" growing="" shoes="" without="" hiking="" say="" barefooters="" local="" most,="" loftier="" bit="" ascent="" barefoot="" baker's="" said.="" could="" knew="" so="" kilimanjaro,="" than="" harder="" lot="" hell="" "longs="" crazy.="" baker="" but="" crazy."="" quite="" is="" climbing="" everyone="" about="" just="" "i="" said,="" barefoot,="" kili="" climb="" try="" crazy="" it="" thought="" would've="" guides="" whether="" asked="" before.="" that="" like="" request="" a="" made="" ever="" had="" one="" no="" though="" even="" sure,="" paschall="" barefoot.="" attempt="" she'd="" sure="" make="" reach,="" within="" adventures="" boulder's="" owner="" paschall,="" robin="" agent,="" travel="" her="" with="" checked="" year,="" last="" peak="" highest="" africa's="" --="" mountain="" 19,336-foot="" trip="" the="" booked="" she="" when="" boulder.="" of="" baker,="" said="" it,"="" welcoming="" really="" not="" were="" and="" it,="" do="" able="" be="" to="" going="" was="" i="" think="" didn't="" they="" value="When Sonnet Baker showed up at the bottom of Mount Kilimanjaro ready to hike up the mountain barefoot, her guides had doubts. " name="article">
```

All the others `<input>` fields work fine.
 Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use `htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES)` when putting data in HTML-attributes:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="article" value="'.htmlspecialchars($row['article'], ENT_QUOTES).'" />';
```

Also, google for XSS-attacks.

Comment: Thank you very much, This worked. If you have time can you explain why? This form is on a back end of the site. So I was being a little more relaxed with the security. Bad Idea? Again thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Any stray quote in a variable effectively terminates the attribute. The user agent (your browser) is then effectively left with garbage in the html tag, and does it's best to interpret their meaning to the best of its capabilities, which it will of course get wrong. These kinds of problems are often not malicious (though they can be), so, no, you can't skip those in backends.  And on a side note: most data in companies is destroyed by disgruntled insiders rather then outsiders.... Security is a must ;)